# When multiple resumes cmi.core.score.raw is improper

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

When I make multiple resumes attempt to a single course the `cmi.core.score.raw` score is not updated properly.

Suppose there are 5 sections in the course. If the user successfully completes the 2 sections, then exits the score is proper (say 30). While the user resumes the course, it starts with the proper position and even if the user correctly answers all the question correctly, the score is not updating to 100 ( it saves as 70-80 ). It shows the result as **failed** which is wrong since the user has answered all the questions correctly.

I thought it may be due to the **suspend_data** max limit posed by SCORM 1.2, but the course resumes at the correct location every time. So I am confused about what may be causing this behavior?

I also tried the same course in **scormcloud**, there also the same issue persists.

Are there any settings which we need to take care while creating the SCORM 1.2 package which may have caused this issue?

Has anyone faced this issue previously? I googled and couldn't find the appropriate answer. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** I'm attaching the scromcloud launch history image which will clearly show the score value at launch start and end.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SCO is typically responsible for conducting the "math" portion since it maintains the cmi.core.score section of the student attempt.

You're correct to assume something with the suspend data may not be giving the SCO's capability of determining a history of correct/incorrect but deeper analysis would be required within the logic of the SCO to find out if it fully supported being put back in a position it left off in.

SCORM 1.2 was mostly a 'optional' standard in regards to the support of the Student Attempt.  And even though the standard often states there are character limits it typically was optionally enforced by the LMS.

So something to possibly evaluate whats going on within the SCO while using it on a LMS would be to try out the bookmarklet on https://cybercussion.com or see if you can locate the deeper logs on SCORM cloud which show the actual data being stored.  Its always possible the suspend data is obfuscated but since you said SCORM 1.2 I'm going to say doubtful.  It may be semi-human readable.

Fail that we'd need to dig into the SCO code base to determine how it "puts itself back" after obtaining the suspend data.  To do that I'd search the code base for "cmi.suspend_data" to maybe help locate it.